# Break/Stoping *NgFor loop in Angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an ***NgFor** loop to write the rows of a table.  But I would like to show only the first 10 results.
Is there a way to **break/stop the loop**?

Somenthing like that:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <td>{{row.myCol1}}</td>
    <td>{{row.myCol2}}</td>
    <td>{{row.myCol2}}</td>
    ...
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular [`slice`](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) pipe's one of the application is for slicing arrays (other being slicing string).

Try the following

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let row of rows | slice:0:10">
    <td>{{row.myCol1}}</td>
    <td>{{row.myCol2}}</td>
    <td>{{row.myCol2}}</td>
    ...
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use index in for loop.

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let row of rows;let i = index">
      <ng-container *ngIf="i <= 10">
         <td>{{row.myCol1}}</td>
         <td>{{row.myCol2}}</td>
         <td>{{row.myCol3}}</td>
       </ng-container>
 </ng-container>
```

Or you can create subarray in your ts and iterate over it.

```
n: number = 10;
const subArray = rows.slice(0, n);
```